# feature not working when updating from from fancybox 1.3.4 to 2.0.1

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I´m not a coder, so I might ask wrong :)

Was using this little code to open a fancybox when clicking on a div:

```
jQuery('.myDivWithClass').each(function() {
    var actualDiv = jQuery(this);
    actualDiv.fancybox({
        'href' :actualDiv.find('a').attr('href') + '?removeHtmlHeader=1'
    });
});
```

Now... it worked, but when I change to the new Version it doesn´. Why???

(if you think: what was he doing? i´m using a CMS and tried to provide a simple solution for the user - by creating a simple -hidden - link.)
html:

```
<div class="myDivWithClass">
    <h3>Headline</h3>
    <p>Some Text.</p>
    <p><a class="hidden" href="theHiddenLink.html">Link</a></p>
</div>
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: Can you please tell us what the ?removeHtmlHeader=1 does. I'm assuming this has something to do with your CMS (WP?)

Comment: yes, the " '?removeHtmlHeader=1' " removes all header-data when loading a page from the cms (typo3 4.5)

Comment: Take a look at my answer below; your code is correct which leaves either a conflict or incorrect jQuery version as a potential source of the problem.

Comment: Maybe set type, e.g. { href : 'your_href', type : 'iframe' }

Comment: Nope - i use jQuery 1.7.0. btw. i remove the header because all the .js is not loaded a second time :)

Comment: I´ll try to set the type, thanks for all your answers up to now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FancyBox 1.3.4 uses jQuery 1.4; while FancyBox 2.0+ requires jQuery 1.7+; check to ensure you updated the version of jQuery being used by your CMS and that there aren't two versions being used at the same time (thereby conflicting).

I hope this helps!

Comment: Fancybox 2 works well with jQuery v1.4.2 + (it's always a good idea to use the latest version though)... It would be much helpful to see a link with an example of the issue

Comment: As mentioned above, i use jQuery 1.7 and no other library (except jQuery UI).

It works to the point that the lightbox opens - but no content is displayed (and loaded, as i can see in firebug). when using the 'old' fancybox i can see the "GET"-Aktion.

Comment: Thanks all of you:

{type : ajax } did the magix for me :)